# How to read a MemoryFile with rasterio

Tags: python, rasterio, alignment

I'm working with images from different sources in python and even though they have the same pixel size and are clipped to the same rectangle, their shapes don't match (probably because of issues during reprojecting one). So I'm trying to align one based on the information of the other using rasterio so I can do some math with them. The idea though, is doing everything in memory (I don't want to store anything in my hard disk).

I wrote the function below. It takes a dict with the metadata of a reference raster and a numpy array which I want to align.

```
def align_rasters(ref_profile: dict, data_to_align: np.array):
    
    # Write data to memory with reference profile
    with MemoryFile() as memfile: # memfile stores the new file as bytes
        with memfile.open(**ref_profile) as dataset:
            dataset.write(data_to_align, indexes=1)

    return memfile
```

The function works and it is returning the, hopefully, correctly aligned data. I want now to open the memfile and get the numpy array it contains, but I haven't been able to do so.

The documentation says the MemoryFile "implements the Python file protocol and provides read(), seek(), and tell() methods". When I try to read it, however, I get a Windows Fatal Exception and have to restart the python kernel in spyder.

Does anyone knows how to solve this or if there's another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. During my tries I was placing the another with with the memfile closed. This function does what I wanted.

```
def align_rasters(ref_profile: dict, data_to_align: np.array) -> (np.array, dict):
    
    # Write date to memory with reference profile
    with MemoryFile() as memfile: # memfile stores the new file as bytes
        with memfile.open(**ref_profile) as dataset:
            dataset.write(data_to_align, indexes=1)

        with memfile.open() as dataset:
            data = dataset.read(1)
            profile = dataset.profile
        
    return data, profile
```

This helped me to figure it out: [enter link description here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/443822/how-do-you-reproject-a-raster-using-rasterio-in-memory)